# Keep clock as lock screen

Tags: 18.04, lock-screen, notification

In ubuntu 18.04 when I lock screen I see digital clock and notifications but it goes off after a second, it is the same screen that is shown during unlocking.

How can I prevent this screen - with clock and notifications - from disappearing while locking?

Reason: I would like to know if there is a notification without having to come to the computer and pressing a button.

Comment: try `no-screenblank` gnome-extensions

Answer (score 2):

Just as [PRATAP](https://askubuntu.com/users/739431/pratap) mentioned:

> try `no-screenblank` gnome-extensions

[No Screen Blank](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2413/no-screen-blank/) does exactly that. I used firefox extension to use it. Instalation process is just a click on on/off switch.

Comment: @PRATAP, copy this answer and I will remove this one and accept yours - I can not (or at least I am not aware that I can) accept a comment. Quick fixero :)

Comment: no its completely correct to write the own answer.. you need 48hrs time to accept the answer.. so go ahead for waiting and accept your own answer.. good luck in Ask Ubuntu..